# Hello i need to know how to represent an object with this specific in django models

Tags: python, sql, django, sqlite, django-models

I'm creating a web app based on Django for inventory system and i have an object with this specific:
I have a Pallet that contains :

```
class PalletN(models.Model):

    qr_type=models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
    customer_partnum=models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True,null=True)
    partsnum=models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True,null=True)
    boxquantity= models.IntegerField(default='0',blank=True,null=True)
    Ponum =models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
    designation= models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True,null=True)
    production_date=models.DateField(blank=True , null=True)
    suplier=models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
    shipment_date=models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    Customer_code= models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
    Snumber= models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
    status=models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True, null=True)
    creation_date=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    zone=models.ForeignKey(zone,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    rack=models.ForeignKey(rack,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    position=models.ForeignKey(position,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True);
```

My problem is how to represent a Mixt Pallet meaning a mixt pallet can have multiple customer_partnum designation and so on.
i'm reading the data using a Qr code and this an example for better understanding.

Pallet Normal:

```
QR|XX5125B219|2021/07/13|2021/08/26|XXX2125-B|XX-T4311311E-4IX|XX-T43-11311-E-XXX|Some description|300|40|12000|
```

Pallet Mixte:

```
QR|XX5125B182|2021/07/13|2021/08/26|XXX2125-B|
XX-L8814313A-9PX|XX-L88-14313-G-XXX|Some description|1000|12|12000|
XX-L8814314A-9PX|XX-L88-14314-G-XXX|Some description|1000|13|13000|
XX-L8814316E-9PX|XX-L88-14316-E-XXX|Some description|1000|15|15000|
```

in the case of pallet mixte i have a lot of references for the user to add a new mixte pallet it's a bit chalenging to choose between them if i a do a drop down menu it will contain like 200 and plus reference and as i told you befor a mixte pallet can have 2 or plus references.

I would love your sugestions if that's possible
THANK YOU

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code!

Comment: Hello I'm scaning boxes and pallets using Qr code scanner and storing the data in a database in the case of pallets i have 2 type normal ones and mixte ones  how can i store a mixte pallet in my database and how to represent it in the models

Answer (score 0):

You can use ManytoManyField instead of CharField. [You can have a look here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

Comment: Thank you for your feed back i'll look into it